# What is a Linux IP route without outgoing network interface (RTLINK answer lacking `RTA_OIF`) and how do I create one for testing?

Tags: linux, routing, iproute

When using RTLINK to query the available IP route from a (network-namespaced) Linux kernel, I noticed that on one test system RTLINK returns a route without a `RTA_OIF` attribute, that is, without an outgoing network interface being specified.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to reproduce this situation (for testing) using the `ip route add` command and so far no person within my reach was able to explain "what" originally created this route without any indication of an outgoing network interface. From a look into the Linux kernel sources I noticed that the outgoing network interface attribute in fact is optional. However, my attempts at `ip route add` always end up with either an outgoing network interface automatically added by the kernel or a not reachable:

`ip route add 1.1.1.1/32 via 1.1.1.2` gives `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`.

Next (failed) attempt:

```
ip addr add 1.1.1.2/32 dev ens33
ip route add 1.1.1.1/32 via 1.1.1.2
ip route show
```

... then gives `1.1.1.1 via 1.1.1.2 dev ens33`, where the kernel automatically inserted a suitable outgoing network interface (and thus `RTA_OIF` is present, even if I didn't specify it in the beginning).

Searching for things like "linux ip route without outgoing interface" or similar gives me no usable results -- unless I'm overlooking something important here.

So, how can I create a (test) case where I have an IP route without an outgoing network interface? What am I overlooking here?

Comment: My gut feeling is that a route without an outgoing interface makes no sense (what should the kernel do with a packet for this route? After all, a route is there to answer the question "which interface should I pass this packet to"). So if you found one, it may be a bug. Or a really unusual situation. The only situation I can think of where this *could* make sense is in policy routing, where the next action is "consult some other table before deciding what to do". So maybe look into policy routing with complicated tables?

Comment: I now got more information and it turns out that these are (at least) 'blackhole' and 'unreachable' routes: blackholes tell the IP stack to silently drop IP packets, while unreachable routes trigger ICMP(v6) unreachable messages. Maybe there are more cases...?

Comment: BTW, you can also answer your own question (and accept the answer). This will help other people with the same question. And I didn't think of blockhole/unreachable routes, good catch.

Comment: :) I know and I probably did too many times in the past, so I wanted to wait for maybe some more information flowing in before answering myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that routes without outgoing network interfaces (not: rules, which are related to routing) are used for at least for these three use cases:

1. so-called **blackhole** routes, where the IP stack silently drops all traffic matching the route.
2. **unreachable** routes, where the IP stack drops all traffic destined to these routes, and additionally triggers an ICMP(v6) unreachable response.
3. **prohibit** routes, where again the IP stack drops all traffic, also sends an ICMP(v6) response, but this times a "prohibited" instead of "unreachable".

These routes can be easily created as follows:

```
# ip route add blackhole 1.2.3.4
# ip route add unreachable 1.2.3.5
# ip route add prohibit 1.2.3.6
```

An `ip route show` then confirms that these routes don't have outgoing network interfaces:

```
$ ip route show
...
blackhole 1.2.3.4
unreachable 1.2.3.5
prohibit 1.2.3.6
```